# Determine when animation of UIPickerView is started/stopped?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

Is there a way to determine when the animation of wheel spinning of Picker is started and when finished ? 
I have looked in delegate methods of UIPickerView but did not see any useful information.

Comment: 7 years later, but maybe somebody need an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070723/is-there-any-way-to-tell-if-uipickerview-is-spinning