# Is there any way to tell if UIPickerView is spinning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

Is there any way to tell if UIPickerView is spinning?
I need to disable some UI elements when it is in transition.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304839/determining-if-uipickerwheel-is-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

There are no delegate method for this however you can check the `animationKeys` count since a `UIPickerView` is a subclass of `UIView`:

```
BOOL isSpinning = myPickerView.layer.animationKeys.count > 0;

if(isSpinning){
   NSLog(@"disable");
}else{
   NSLog(@"enable");
}
```

Maybe `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` is maybe a good place to put this code ?

Comment: Doesn't work. I think I'm going to save the row number in the didSelectRow event and compare it to selectedRowInComponent. If they are not equal, it is spinning.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by saving the row number in `didSelectRow` and comparing it to the row in `selectedRowInComponent`.

```
-(BOOL) isCardPickerSpinning{
return (lastCardPickerRow != [cardPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]);}
```

I also created a boolean that will be used to call a method when the spinner is put in motion.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 lastCardPickerRow = row;
 pickerInMotion = NO;
 //update UI code goes here
 eventSwitch.enabled = YES;
}

 -(void)pickerViewMotionStart
{
    //disable my UI
    eventSwitch.enabled = NO;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component
       reusingView:(UIView *)view {

UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;
 if (pickerLabel == nil) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200, 32);
    pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    pickerLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
 }
 if (!pickerInMotion)
 {
    pickerInMotion = YES;
    [self pickerViewMotionStart];
 }
 pickerLabel.text = @"SomeString";
 return pickerLabel;

}
```

Comment: Yes, using a timer is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

**JVC's solution in Swift 4.2**

**1. Create 2 variables**

```
var lastPickedRow = 0
var pickerInMotion: Bool = false
```

**2. Saving the row number in `didSelectRow` and comparing it to the row in `selectedRowInComponent`.**

```
var isPickerSpinning: Bool {
    return lastPickedRow != pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
}
```

**3. Create a method to call, when motion started**

```
func pickerViewMotionStart(){
    //Do something when motion started
    button.alpha = 0
}
```

**4. In `didSelectRow`**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    lastPickedRow = row
    pickerInMotion = false
    //Do something when motion ended
    button.alpha = 1
}
```

**5. In `viewForRow`**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    //create a label to write something
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pickerView.frame.width, height: 40)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    label.textAlignment = .center

    //Check if picker is moving or not        
    if !pickerInMotion {
        pickerInMotion = true
        self.pickerViewMotionStart()
    }
    label.text = "something"
    return label
}
```